# Can I dispatch object rather than just strings?

Tags: reactjs, redux

This works great:

```
this.props.dispatch( { type: 'myType', text: 'hello' } )
```

I was wondering if I can dispatch objects rather than just a string?

Comment: Anything brother, you can dispatch anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only `required property` of an `action` is `type`, every other property is arbitrary. As long as your reducer knows how to deal with it you can `dispatch` pretty much anything (including `Components`).

```
dispatch({
    type: 'MY_ACTION',
    data: {
        arr: [],
        str: 'foo',
    }
})

const Reducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'MY_ACTION' return {
            ...state,
            myArr : action.data.arr
        }

        default : return state
    }
}
```

Comment: And even then your type doesn't even need to be a string... it just needs to be recognizable by your reducer.